# In Access 2007, is it possible to loop though items in a custom category?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the Navigation Pane of Access 2007, we have the "Custom" category and can create a custom category, name it something, and add tables, queries, etc. Is it possible with VBA to loop though all the items in a custom category?

For example, I created a category named "Validations" and it contains 5 queries. I'd like to loop through each query and run it. In pseudocode, it would look like this:

```
For Each Query in Validations
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query"
```

EDIT: I started looking into it, and it looks like I need to access the MSysNavPaneGroups table to get the ID of my custom group. In my case, ID = 235

Additionally, is it possible to create an Excel spreadsheet during this process, and if the query returns >0 rows, have it paste the rows into Sheet1, Sheet2, etc? Something like:

```
Count = 1

For Each Query in Validations
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query"
    If Query.Rows > 0
        Excel.Sheet(i).Name = Query.Name
        Excel.Sheet(i).Rows = Query.Rows
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
```

I haven't even started to look into the Excel part myself, so it's ok if you don't want to mess with it. I'm more concerned about looping through the queries in the custom category.

As always, thank you!

EDIT: I created a query named "GetValidationNames" using Gord's SQL below:

```
SELECT MSysNavPaneGroups.Name AS GroupName, MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.Name AS ObjectName
FROM MSysNavPaneGroups INNER JOIN MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects 
    ON MSysNavPaneGroups.Id = MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.GroupID
WHERE (((MSysNavPaneGroups.GroupCategoryID)=3))
ORDER BY MSysNavPaneGroups.Name, MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.Name;
```

Then created a form with a button, and in the Button_Click() I added the following:

```
Dim rs as Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("GetValidationNames")

Do While Not rs.EOF
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, rs("ObjectName"), _
        "C:\users\username\Desktop\ValidationResults.xlsx"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

This runs all the queries, and adds each one as a new tab to the existing Excel file "ValidationResults.xlsx"

Comment: Examine the `MSysNavPane*` system tables.  They hold information about the groups and which db objects are associated with them.  I've no idea about the proper way to retrieve the information you want, though ... I don't see any methods in the object model.

Comment: @HansUp thank you .. I see I can get the Group ID from MSysNavPaneGroups and the query IDs from MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects

Comment: Yeah, you can probably create a new query to return the names of the queries which are members of the custom group.  However, I'm hesitant to depend on querying system tables.  I got turned off when I saw reports of people encountering *"no read permission"* on `MSysObjects` with Access 2007.  I don't know whether you might encounter similar problem attempting to read `MSysNavPane*` tables.

Comment: @HansUp I haven't run into any problems using [MSys*] tables from within Access itself, although they *are* completely inaccessible (AFAIK) if you connect to an .mdb/.accdb file via OLEDB.

Comment: @HansUp, Gord's query below was able to return the names of the queries in my specific custom category. Now it's just a matter of looping through the query results and running the queries. I'm doing all of this from within Access, so OLEDB isn't going to be an issue. I'll probably end up creating a form with a button that does the work.

Comment: @GordThompson I only experienced it once or twice myself.  But it wasn't an issue limited to OleDb --- from within an Access session, I wasn't allowed to open `MSysObjects` in Datasheet View.

Comment: I'm not surprised, Jeff.  Could be I'm just over cautious.  I think you should accept Gord's answer and break the "export to Excel" piece into a separate question.  When/if you do that, tell us whether you want those queries exported to separate workbooks or as separate sheets within one workbook.

Comment: Ok .. I'm going to see what I can do with looping thru the queries and try to get that working .. then once I have some code I'll post a new question about the Excel part. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just cooked this up so I haven't given it any rigorous testing, but it seems to list all of the objects assigned to custom categories

```
SELECT MSysNavPaneGroups.Name AS GroupName, MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.Name AS ObjectName
FROM MSysNavPaneGroups INNER JOIN MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects 
    ON MSysNavPaneGroups.Id = MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.GroupID
WHERE (((MSysNavPaneGroups.GroupCategoryID)=3))
ORDER BY MSysNavPaneGroups.Name, MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.Name;
```

It could likely be extended to return object types if a category contained more than one type of object (e.g., tables and queries).

Comment: thank you .. this did work to return the list of queries (objects) in the specific custom group :)

Comment: @JeffBrady You're welcome. re: the Excel part -- If you don't want to mess with Excel automation directly you could store your counts in an Access table and use `docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,...` to export it to Excel when you're finished.

Comment: Yeah that probably makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Very useful, thanks! I have over 200 custom groups, and despite the Search facility, struggle to find in which Group a particular object is in - esp if it's in the wrong group :)  The query now makes that easy, after adding table MSysNavPaneObjectIDs and it's field 'Name'. Cheers!